# How to correct a graph in waveform

Tags: integration, graphing-functions

A study that involved recording the maxima of contours of a set of images, was intended at generating a line graph. The graph is of an irregular waveform, as shown in the image. I would like to know if there exists any algorithm that can be accessed to generate a normalized wave. Every peak of the wave corresponds to the contraction phase of the heart.
[The image shows the irregular graph ][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJd3.png)

Comment: In this context, what do you mean by normalization? Is it something like that the average is zero , etc ... ?

Comment: Any method that can be used to correct the irregular graph. As you can see the amplitude of every wavelet is varying, and so is the depression. Initially, I went through the following article http://oaji.net/articles/2017/3667-1483358909.pdf, to see if it could be of any help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you wish to produce here, or do with the results. What would the ideal result look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture where I have shown the irregular graph and a corrected version upon testing with a code from stackoverflow, but is bit confusing. I would like to know if any mathematical method can be applied.